# Spring Autowire: why ApplicationContext is creating two Employee objects for each Department object?

Tags: java

**My Code is:

```
public class Department {

    //Fields
    private Employee manager;

    //Constructor
    public Department()
    {
        System.out.println("Department object created");
    }
    //Setter and getter methods for manager field
}
public class Employee {

    //Fields
    private Integer empno;
    private String empName;
    private Double salary;

    //Constructor
    public Employee()
    {
        System.out.println("Employee object created");
    }
    //Setter and getter methods for empno, empName and salary fileds
}
```

spring configuration file:
    applicationContext.xml:

```
    <bean id="department1" class="spring.beans.Department" autowire="byType" >
    </bean>

    <bean name="employee" class="spring.beans.Employee" scope="prototype">
        <property name="empno" value="123" />
        <property name="empName" value="Basha" />
        <property name="salary" value="30000" />
    </bean>
```

Test.java:

```
main(..){
        ApplicationContext container = new ClasspathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    }
```

I got given output:
    Department object created
    Employee object created
    Employee object created

```
Department object created
Employee object created
Employee object created
```

Question:
    why ApplicationContext  is creating two Employee objects for each Department object?**

Comment: that's because you put scope="prototype" on your bean.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_scopes.htm

Comment: @vincent.. using `prototype` means every time someone asks the container for a bean of that type, a new instance is returned but here `Employee` is requested only once because `Department` is singleton.. so I guess the problem is some where else :)

Comment: Do you know what a `prototype` scope means in Spring? If not then you should read instead of posting such naive questions here.

Comment: @Nazgul do you know what good manners are? Clearly not!

Comment: @basha.. Is that your complete code in main ?

Comment: @BenThurley: What's bad in manners about asking someone to RTFM before posting queries? Not reading the docs shows laziness which is not advocated at SF IMHO.

Comment: @Nazgul 1. It's their first question so give them a chance to learn the site. 2. They clearly have been reading up on this to find a tutorial. 3. The spring docs say prototype means you get a new instance every time you ask for one. They only requested one instance to wire into the Department object. Where's the second instance being created? I suppose spring could create one when it first registers the bean in the context but why would it if it creates a new one each time anyway? Can't see any mention of that in the docs.

Comment: Okie Ben. Maybe you are right. The newbies do merit a benefit of doubt. But surely the docs can't explain each and every scenario that the code is supposed to be written and behave. It is expected of the readers to understand that and exercise their own logical judgement. Simply turning the debug logging on reveals enough to teach someone how spring works. That's something what differentiates a good programmer from a bad one. I do agree with you about giving time to new folks to learn up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

From my side its look like spring container first creating Department bean,As you have auto-wire department bean with Employee so its creating Employee and injecting that in the Department bean .Use auto-wired by constructor and see if it is created while creating department constructor.After that Spring container creating Employee bean its self.

Thanks,
Himanshu

Comment: Only singleton beans are created when you create App Context, prototype scoped beans are created as and when they're requested.